# QtQuick Layouts: Why don't the width and height settings affect anything inside the ColumnLayout?

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, qml, size

I've been working with QtQuick and have encountered an issue I can't quite wrap my head around.

In the example below, I've set the width and height of the Rectangle directly, expecting it to fill 10% of the parent's height and the full width. But, the Rectangle's size is zero

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Window")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.1
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I modify the code to use Layout.preferredWidth and Layout.preferredHeight instead, the Rectangle sizes are as expected:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Window")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.1
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone please explain this behavior?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Layouts in QML calculates the size of its children based on the propertyies set for them in the compount **Layout** property. To get an basic idea of QML Layouts I recommend to read the documentation:

[QT Quick Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicklayouts-overview.html)

Especially [this section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicklayouts-overview.html#specifying-preferred-size) will give you your answere.

And as you already found out, you can not define the congret height and width for an item inside a layout. You have to use other means like *preferredWidth* and *preferredHeight*